# BrowserModule has already been loaded. Angular 13

Tags: angular

I've the problem indicated in the title in a corporate project and I can't figure out what's the problem.
The project is running far before my arrival and this problem is appeared during the angular update from angular 12 to angular 13.

In this project there is an application that is used standalone (mainly for component testing purpose in local environment, so we can edit and not commit the edit in the worst scenario) that is also a library for the main project.

The library couldn't work standalone, and the main project launch the

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
```

error in browser console.

I'm in a lose/lose situation right now

I followed other thread about this problem, but seems not be able to help figuring out what's the problem in my situation.

I tried to remove things from library or from project, but nothing make the project work, so i'm basically without any other idea.

These are the modules of the library and the project itself, and really i don't catch the problem.

**Library**

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
    libraryServicesModule.forRoot(),
    libraryServicesForChildModule.forChild(),
    libraryComponentsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

libraryService.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class libraryServicesModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<libraryServicesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: libraryServicesModule,
      providers: [
        *someComponentsServices*
      ]
    }
  }

  static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders<libraryServicesModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: libraryServicesModule,
      providers: [
        *otherComponentsServices*
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = <any>{
    // 'swipe': {velocity: 0.4, threshold: 20} // override default settings
  };
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    *components*
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    ChartsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    DragDropModule,
    ObserversModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' }),
    NgxPopperModule.forRoot({}),
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
    FileUploadModule,
    *someComponentsServices*
    NgxCaptchaModule,
    NgxSliderModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    MatIconModule,
    *otherComponents*
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  exports: [
    *components*
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: CustomHammerConfig },
  ]
})
export class JarvisComponentsModule {
}
```

package.json - dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "~2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "~0.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "~6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "~6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "~6.4.2",
    "@types/estree": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.4",
    "angular2-notifications": "9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "~4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "~2.9.4",
    "hamburgers": "~1.2.1",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "jquery": "~3.5.1",
    "ng2-charts": "~2.4.3",
    "ng2-file-upload": "~2.0.0-3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "~8.0.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "~11.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "~11.1.5",
    "ngx-popper": "~7.0.0",
    "popper.js": "~1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.4.0",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.13.0",
    "@ngx-builders/analyze": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "bundle-scss": "~1.3.4",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "latest",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-packagr": "^13.3.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5"
  }
```

**Project**

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PublicPageComponent,
    DisambiguationPageComponent,
    AppScrollContainerDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    libraryServicesModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [AppConfigLoader,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (configLoader: AppConfigLoader) => () => configLoader.load(),
      deps: [AppConfigLoader, HttpClient],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CacheInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

shared.module.ts

```
const imports: any[] = [
  CommonModule,
  *libraryProviders*,
  *libraryComponents*,
  libraryServicesModule.forChild(),
  TranslateModule
];

const exports: any[] = [
  CommonModule,
  *libraryProviders*,
  *libraryComponents*,
  libraryServicesModule,
  TranslateModule,
  CapitalizefirstPipe,
  AppendpunctuationmarkPipe,
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CapitalizefirstPipe,
    AppendpunctuationmarkPipe,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ErrorCompanyComponent,
    MaintenancePageComponent,
  ],
  imports: imports,
  exports: exports
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "~0.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "~6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "~6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "~6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "~6.4.2",
    *"@library": "library,*
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/async": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "angular2-notifications": "9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "~4.5.3",
    "hammerjs": "~2.0.8",
    "jquery": "~3.5.1",
    "lodash": "~4.17.20",
    "moment": "2.23.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "~8.0.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "~11.0.0",
    "ngx-popper": "~7.0.0",
    "popper.js": "~1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "bundle-scss": "^1.3.4",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.15.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "ng-packagr": "^13.3.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "latest"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "~2.3.2"
  }
```

Comment: What will happend if you remove BrowserModule from app.module.ts ?

Comment: The behaviour not change

Comment: The configuration that is now not working, was correctly working before updating Angualr from 12 to 13